# Can't ping host with two interfaces

Tags: routing, linux-networking, ping, ipv4

I am trying to figure out why a network interface is not pingable and is returning an ICMP type 3 code 1 response: **Destination unreachable (host unreachable)**.

I am trying to ping from host1 to one of two interfaces on host2. What is odd is that if I ping from host2 to host1 the ping is successful and the original ping (host1 to host2) then suddenly starts to work. After some time the original problem comes back and I am again unable to ping from host1 to host2. I think this has to do with routes and the fact that I have two interfaces on host2. Here are the details:

Try to ping from **host1** (*172.16.44.18*) to **host2** (*10.2.80.129*). No response is returned to host1 (100% packet loss)

```
root@host1:~$ ping 10.2.80.129
PING 10.2.80.129 (10.2.80.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.2.80.129 ping statistics ---
1201 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1228803ms
```

Here are the interfaces and routes on host2.

```
root@host2:~# ip --brief -4 addr
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8
veth-int-core@if183 UP             10.2.80.129/22
veth-mgmt@if185  UP             10.2.28.65/22

root@host2:~# ip route show
default via 10.2.28.1 dev veth-mgmt
10.2.28.0/22 dev veth-mgmt proto kernel scope link src 10.2.28.65
10.2.80.0/22 dev veth-int-core proto kernel scope link src 10.2.80.129
```

The reverse path filtering is set to 2:

```
root@host2:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/veth-int-core/rp_filter 
2
```

I can see the ICMP echo request come in over interface veth-int-core but I never see an ICMP echo response.

```
root@host2:~# tcpdump -nei veth-int-core icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on veth-int-core, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:42:51.117858 e4:aa:5d:99:88:4a > 00:16:3e:f7:fa:c8, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.16.44.18 > 10.2.80.129: ICMP echo request, id 177, seq 3, length 64
12:42:52.141535 e4:aa:5d:99:88:4a > 00:16:3e:f7:fa:c8, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.16.44.18 > 10.2.80.129: ICMP echo request, id 177, seq 4, length 64
12:42:53.165507 e4:aa:5d:99:88:4a > 00:16:3e:f7:fa:c8, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.16.44.18 > 10.2.80.129: ICMP echo request, id 177, seq 5, length 64
12:42:54.189568 e4:aa:5d:99:88:4a > 00:16:3e:f7:fa:c8, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.16.44.18 > 10.2.80.129: ICMP echo request, id 177, seq 6, length 64
```

When I look at the loopback interface I can see the destination unreachable response

```
root@host2:~# tcpdump -nei lo icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:43:52.903768 00:00:00:00:00:00 > 00:00:00:00:00:00, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 126: 10.2.80.129 > 10.2.80.129: ICMP host 172.16.44.18 unreachable, length 92
12:43:52.903774 00:00:00:00:00:00 > 00:00:00:00:00:00, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 126: 10.2.80.129 > 10.2.80.129: ICMP host 172.16.44.18 unreachable, length 92
12:43:52.903779 00:00:00:00:00:00 > 00:00:00:00:00:00, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 126: 10.2.80.129 > 10.2.80.129: ICMP host 172.16.44.18 unreachable, length 92
12:43:55.975774 00:00:00:00:00:00 > 00:00:00:00:00:00, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 126: 10.2.80.129 > 10.2.80.129: ICMP host 172.16.44.18 unreachable, length 92
```

When I look at the packets in Wireshark I can see the type 3 code 1 response:

[image: Wireshark capture]

However, if I ping host1 (172.16.44.18) from host2 the original ping from host1 (172.16.44.18) to host2 (10.2.80.129) starts to work. Note that this ping goes out interface veth-mgmt (10.2.28.65) as that is the default route.

```
root@host2:~# ping 172.16.44.18
PING 172.16.44.18 (172.16.44.18) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.44.18: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=4.06 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.44.18: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=4.05 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.44.18: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=4.12 ms
^C
--- 172.16.44.18 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.052/4.079/4.122/0.060 ms

root@host1:~$ ping 10.2.80.129
PING 10.2.80.129 (10.2.80.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.2.80.129: icmp_seq=488 ttl=62 time=1021 ms
64 bytes from 10.2.80.129: icmp_seq=489 ttl=62 time=4.09 ms
64 bytes from 10.2.80.129: icmp_seq=490 ttl=62 time=4.05 ms
64 bytes from 10.2.80.129: icmp_seq=491 ttl=62 time=4.07 ms
64 bytes from 10.2.80.129: icmp_seq=492 ttl=62 time=4.09 ms
64 bytes from 10.2.80.129: icmp_seq=493 ttl=62 time=4.20 ms
^C
--- 10.2.80.129 ping statistics ---
493 packets transmitted, 6 received, 98.783% packet loss, time 503706ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.054/173.652/1021.412/379.129 ms
```

If I wait several minutes the problem comes back and I'm unable to ping host2 from host1.

What could cause this type of problem? I feel it has to be something related to routing. It looks like host2 doesn't know how to route back to host1, but then when you try to ping host1 from host2 it learns that route.

When I ping host1 from host2 and get everything working the ICMP packets arrive on veth-int-core and are sent out on veth-mgmt but use the source address of 10.2.80.129

```
root@host2:~# tcpdump -nvei any icmp
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
16:35:15.659341  In e4:aa:5d:99:88:4a ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 59067, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.16.44.18 > 10.2.80.129: ICMP echo request, id 202, seq 51, length 64
16:35:15.659361 Out 00:16:3e:e4:13:09 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56778, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.2.80.129 > 172.16.44.18: ICMP echo reply, id 202, seq 51, length 64
16:35:16.660651  In e4:aa:5d:99:88:4a ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: (tos 0x0, ttl 62, id 59204, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.16.44.18 > 10.2.80.129: ICMP echo request, id 202, seq 52, length 64
16:35:16.660670 Out 00:16:3e:e4:13:09 ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56854, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    10.2.80.129 > 172.16.44.18: ICMP echo reply, id 202, seq 52, length 64
```

Comment: You should check with `tcpdump` whether the working ping from host1 to 10.2.80.129 arrives on the other interface.

Comment: @HaukeLaging thanks, I checked this and the working ping arrives on veth-int-core and responds back from veth-int-core.

Comment: What is the output of `ip route get 172.16.44.18` during the working and the non-working phases?

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken it goes out with a source IP address of 10.2.80.129 but uses the MAC address of veth-mgmt. So the packet is actually sent using veth-mgmt. I still think this is correct as I have rp_filter set to 2 so it accepts the packet and then routes it out veth-mgmt but sets the source IP address to 10.2.80.129. Looking into the `ip route get` once I reproduce the error again.

Comment: So the `ip route get` was showing the same thing when it was working and not work. I don't know exactly what the problem was but I ended up restarting the container host and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `rp_filter`. If you ping 172.16.44.18 then the packet is sent to the default gateway i.e. through `veth-mgmt`. The pings from 172.16.44.18 to 10.2.80.129 arrive on `veth-int-core` and are dropped due to reverse path filtering.

Comment: So what should it be set to if not 2? As per the kernel documentation: "2 - Loose mode as defined in RFC3704 Loose Reverse Path. Each incoming packet's source address is also tested against the FIB and if the source address is not reachable via any interface the packet check will fail." The packet should come in on veth-int-core as you stated and the system should realize that the source packet is routable and respond back. Changing the rp_filter to 0 DOES NOT fix the problem.